# Problem compiling with NuGet package (warning MSB3277)

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Today I updated my Nuget packages that use the Microsoft Graph API system and now I get a lot of warnings related to `System.Net.Http`.

In my `App.config` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
   ...
   ...
```

The actual warnings I am getting are:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll].
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll".
            System.Net.Http
    References which depend on "System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.17.0\lib\net461\Azure.Core.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.17.0\lib\net461\Azure.Core.dll".
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.17.0\lib\net461\Azure.Core.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
        C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll".
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
        C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll".
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
        C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identity.client\4.35.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identity.client\4.35.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll".
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identity.client\4.35.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
        C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.logging\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.logging\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll".
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.logging\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.tokens\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt\6.12.0\lib\net461\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
        C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll".
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
        C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll".
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\6.12.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.2\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
            C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
```

I am compiling with the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

---

I noticed:

> ```
> References which depend on "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,  ...  Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll].
> ```

My app properties is for that framework:

[image]

So do I have to change to a different framework that uses `4.2.0.0`?

I get confused because according to the NuGet Package manager I think the Framework I have is OK.

---

#### Update

My main solution has several shared projects. The above C# project being one of them. There is another Visual Basic project that uses the Google Calendar API an din that project the `App.config` file says:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I notice it is telling it to use `4.0.0.0`. So is the solution here to edit the c# project `App.config` and change the `newVersion` property to match? To stop conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C# Console Application project target .NET Framework includes a reference to *System.Net.Http* by default. If you're not using that reference then you can remove it and that will clear your warning.

Comment: In my Google project (the VB one) it does have a specific Microsoft.Net.Http entry (version 2.2.29) in the list. I don't want to break compiling by removing anything needed by the system. How can we confirm?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, remove it and see what happens. If it breaks then you can always add it back. If worst comes to worst, you can always restore your project from source control if you break it.

Comment: Ok. I will try later.

Comment: I commented out the two sections about the `system.http.net` in both files and it worked fine. Thanks.